# How does one query the OpenAlias DNSSEC to return an XMR address in Javascript?

Tags: openalias

Is there an example of how one would query the OpenAlias DNSSEC to return an XMR address for a registered alias? And how would one reference an OpenAlias address like http:// ? OA:// ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query OpenAlias is to simply perform a DNS query on TXT records for a given domain. These queries can be secured by utilizing DNSSEC.

Full details of implementing (and more) is all documented at https://openalias.org

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following: https://dns-api.org/

Example output:

https://dns-api.org/TXT/openalias.org

Then use whatever programming language to parse through each TXT transaction and detect the oa prefix and then process each one.

---

Using the above api calls. I made a chrome extension to output open alias addresses by listing out openalias:// or oa:// handlers like this:

oa://donate.getmonero.org
openalias://openalias.org

The chrome extension is here: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blockchain-gateway/mcppmdjlghmadabjofodajpppiloembp